# How can i add parameters like filename, fileSize, fileCreationDate for each audio file in multiple file uploading using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-2, multiple-file-upload

I am uploading multiple audio files using below code

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

```
[manager POST:requestUrl parameters:jsonParameter constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    //add audio data one by one
    for(int i=0; i<[pathArr count];i++)
    {
        AudioFile *audiofile = [pathArr objectAtIndex:i];
        NSData *audioData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:audiofile.filePath];
        NSString *strName = [[pathArr objectAtIndex:i] lastPathComponent];
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:audioData name:strName];
    }

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
    [self.delegate uploadingFileResponseReceieved:responseObject];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

But now i also want to send filename,fileSize and fileCreationDate parameter with each audio file. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Send them as your `parameters`.

Comment: I want to send parameters for each audio file. I did not understand. please give me some example.

Comment: @Daniil : I write as below. Is it what you want me to do ?                                                   [formData appendPartWithFormData:audioData name:strName];
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:(NSData *)audiofile.fileCreationDateAndTime name:@"creationDate"];
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:(NSData *)audiofile.fileDuration name:@"fileDuration"];

Comment: Sorry, mate, I missed the 'for each' part.